# Grails and datatables, don't know how to get data from a column in a selected row

Tags: grails, datatables

I have one column that is used as a link to redirect to an edit view so that column, which originally contains the instance id, is decorated with some html-code. That's all ok but when I want to process selected rows in the table I need to get each rows instance id, but in this case the column is dirty with all this html.

I have tried this but the id is garbled with html.

```
       var arr = [];
       $.each(table.rows('.selected').data(), function() {
           arr.push(this[2]);
           alert('Id: ');
       });
       alert('Data:'+arr);
```

The reason to that it's garbled with html is here from the view:

```
<td> <g:link action="edit" controller="prodBuffer" params="[id:pb.id]"> ${pb.id}</g:link></td>
```

I use this field as a link so I can edit the instance.
Any one who knows what to do?

I solved it by do some simple parsing:

```
            var arr = [];
            $.each(table.rows('.selected').data(), function() {
                var str = this[2];
                var firstIndex = str.indexOf('>')+1;
                var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('<');
                str = str.substring(firstIndex,lastIndex);
                alert(Number(str));
                arr.push(str);
            });
            alert('Data:'+arr);
            $.ajax({
                url: '${g.createLink( controller:'ordersAndStore', action:'createOffer' )}',
                data: {id:arr},
                type: 'get'
            }).success( function ( data ) {window.location = "${createLink(controller:'offerHeader',action:'edit')}"+"/"+data});
```

Comment: So you have a link in each row in column 2 in your datatable which when you click takes you to a new page? Where is the processing going on you mention? Can you show more code?

Comment: I solved it by doing a simple parse of the arr-contents. Se my question above.